# Get user id via mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the two tables grades and feedback and the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT id, mingrade, maxgrade, quizid
FROM feedback
WHERE quizid=6
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6
```

How do I need to modify the query to add userid at the first table?

Comment: hint: INNER JOIN ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html )

Comment: Where is the `userid` column stored?

Comment: in different table: grades

Comment: SELECT mingrade, maxgrade, quizid FROM mdl_quiz_feedback INNER JOIN mdl_quiz_grades WHERE userid = '13' AS quizid LIMIT 6 - what wrong?

Comment: SELECT 
    mingrade, 
    maxgrade, 
    quizid
FROM
    mdl_quiz_grades t1
        INNER JOIN
    mdl_quiz_feedback t2 ON t1.id = t2.quizid - this working, but how i can get by userid?

Comment: Use JOIN or SubQuery .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the fields of the grades and feedback tables? Use a JOIN that links the two based on a common attribute.

```
SELECT column_name(s) 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name
WHERE condition;
```

So if your two tables are grades and feedback, and both have the field userid you could say:

```
SELECT id, userid, mingrade, maxgrade, quizid
FROM feedback
INNER JOIN grades ON feedback.userid = grades.userid
WHERE quizid = 6
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6;
```

I think that should work.